# Can I change SID for a domain user?

Tags: sql-server, windows, active-directory

My scenario: 
I am running windows server and I have AD installed to it. I deleted some users which have configured other system on different server. So, these systems can not access their databases, software configuration etc

What I am looking for?
I did recreate the user but still did not work. So, I think if I re clone it (since I was not able to restore it) it will working fine

Please advice How I can solve this

Comment: The SID in SQL Server is the SID that SQL Server gets from the Domain Controller. You can't change the SID; it's unique to that AD user. If you need to add a new login/user then use the `CREATE LOGIN [Domain\User] FROM WINDOWS;` command.

Comment: If you've deleted that user in the AD, and now have a new user with that same username (feel this is bad practice), you'll need to `DROP` the old logins and users from your SQL Server and then recreate them. If the new AD user should the same permissions as the old one, you'll need to `DROP` and `CREATE` the `LOGIN`, and then `ALTER` the users in the individual databases to use the new `LOGIN`: `ALTER USER [Domain\User] WITH LOGIN = [Domain\User];`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did drop and create the login for SQL and it is working fine but the problem also related to other systems so I am return it the way it was so everything comeback to normal. The user was deleted by mistake but it cause a lot of issues. Also, the new user with same name did not help out so I was thinking to change the SID for  the new user with the old one(I got the old one from logs)

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is impossible. The only way to restore that would be if you enabled the recycle bin.

https://www.lepide.com/how-to/restore-deleted-objects-in-active-directory.html

Answer (score 0):

No. Active Directory simply won't allow you to. The [documentation for the `objectSid` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-objectsid) says:

> Update Frequency                 This value is set by the system when the account is created.

That's it. It can only be set when the account is created.

Most of the SID (Security Identifier) is the SID of the domain. The last number at the end of the SID is the RID (Relative Identifier), which is a number that is incremented with every object created and is never reused.